# Replace rows in a dataframe with rows in another dataframe given multiple columns as keys

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

There are questions similar to this on SO but I am yet to see one exactly like this - replacing with multiple columns as keys.
I have two dataframes. Example below:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame([["X",Monday,1,0],
              ["Y",Tuesday,1,0],
              ["Z",Wednesday,0,0],
              ["Y",Thursday,0,0]],columns=["First","Second","Third", "Fourth"])
```

and

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame([["X",Monday,3,0],
              ["Y",Tuesday,7,1],
              ["Z",Wednesday,6,2]],columns=["First","Second","Third", "Fourth"])
```

What I want is for df2 to replace every 'Third' and 'Fourth' columns in df1 when 'First' and 'Second' columns match. So result will be

```
df3 = pd.DataFrame([["X",Monday,3,0],
              ["Y",Tuesday,7,1],
              ["Z",Wednesday,6,2],
              ["Y",Thursday,0,0]],columns=["First","Second","Third", "Fourth"])
```

I have tried the `update` and `is.in` but they work with index and one column only as far as I know.
Can anyone help please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
(df1.merge(df2, on=['First', 'Second'], how='left', suffixes = ('_old','') )
    .fillna(df1)
    .drop(columns = ['Third_old','Fourth_old'])
)
```

we merge on two columns, then replace NaNs where needed with the original results, and drop unused columns

output

```
   First    Second      Third   Fourth
0   X       Monday      3.0     0.0
1   Y       Tuesday     7.0     1.0
2   Z       Wednesday   6.0     2.0
3   Y       Thursday    0.0     0.0
```

Answer (score 2):

You can still use [`DataFrame.update`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.update.html) to update the values in place using non-nan values from another DataFrame but before using it you have to `align` the indices in both the dataframes:

```
df1 = df1.set_index(['First', 'Second'])
df1.update(df2.set_index(['First', 'Second']))
df1 = df1.reset_index()
```

Result:

```
print(df1)

  First     Second  Third  Fourth
0     X     Monday    3.0     0.0
1     Y    Tuesday    7.0     1.0
2     Z  Wednesday    6.0     2.0
3     Y   Thursday    0.0     0.0
```

Comment: This also worked and it's cleaner. I didn't know you could use multiple indices for `.update`

Comment: @TheDataGuy Happy coding :)